# setTimeout and window.location (location.href) not working

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect user to index.php in 5 seconds, but it redirects me right away. I don't want to use jQuery in this simple code.

```
<script>            
setTimeout(function(){location.href="index.php", 5000} );           
</script>
```

Comment: Move `, 5000` after the `}`...

Comment: @RobW - That sounds like an answer !

Comment: Jesus this was stupid from me @Rob W write this as answer to my question so I can mark it as solution

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is the right way...

```
setTimeout(function(){location.href="index.php"} , 5000);
```

You can check the docs here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

**Syntax :**

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, [delay, param1, param2, ...]);
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, [delay]);
```

**Example :**

```js
WriteDatePlease();
setTimeout(function(){WriteDatePlease();} , 5000);


function WriteDatePlease(){
    var currentDate = new Date()
    var dateAndTime = "Last Sync: " + currentDate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentDate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + currentDate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                + currentDate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + currentDate.getSeconds();
    $('.result').append("<p>" + dateAndTime + "</p>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```
setTimeout ("window.location='index.php'", 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread has already been solved and its somewhat 2 years later that i have come accross this, I personally just used the example from Joan's answer and modified it to work exactly how i need it to as the location.href will not redirect the TOP or Parent page when called within an iframe.

So for anyone looking for a way to redirect after 5 seconds but within an iframe and to redirect the TOP / Parent page aswell here is how i have achieved that based on Joan's answer to the Original Question.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){window.top.location="index.php"} , 5000);
    </script>
```

And if you wanted to call this by using PHP as i personally did do here is how you would use the echo command to redirect the user after 5 seconds.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){window.top.location="index.php"} , 5000);</script>';
```

Hope this helps anyone else searching for the same solution.

Thanks